# curl php grep to a variable for printing

Tags: php, curl

I have tried a few different things in dom, but nothing is quite working yet.  I've got a lot to learn still.  Thank you in advance for any help.

This question is different then one I previously posted. The previous was a shell script to enter information to a database. I need to go in a different direction. This question is just parsing the data in PHP and assign it to a variable so I can show only the pertinent information -- no database or shell scripting, just php.  Can I use regular expressions in someway in php.... like:
    grep -Po '[0-9]+(?=[^0-9]+(C5:2<|C5:6<|C5:13))'

I have a device on my network that provides a table of information for a piece of equipment. I need to be able to curl the site and then parse the values from the table to variables. Below is what the device provides. Can someone help me in how to parse the data from the table to variables? In particular I'm looking for the numbers at the end of C5:1 and C5:5, which currently have the values of 191 and 1506 in this example.

```
<html><head><title>Data Table Monitor</title></head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff"><center>
<h2><font face="helvetica">Ethernet Processor</font></h2>
<h2><i>Data Table Monitor</i></h2>
<hr width=25% align=center>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="15"><body bgcolor="#ffffff"><center><table border=1><tr><th>Address</th><th>CU</th><th>CD</th><th>DN</th><th>OV</th><th>UN</th>    <th>UA</th><th>PRE</th><th>ACC</th><th>Address</th><th>CU</th><th>CD</th><th>DN</th><th>OV</th><th>UN</th><th>PRE</th><th>ACC</th></tr><tr><td>C5:0</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>10</td><td align=right>0</td><td>C5:1</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>32000</td>    <td align=right>191</td></tr><tr><td>C5:2</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>32000</td>    <td align=right>2</td><td>C5:3</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>0</td><td align=right>0</td></tr><tr><td>C5:4</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>0</td><td align=right>0</td><td>C5:5</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>32000</td>   <td align=right>1506</td></tr><tr><td>C5:6</td>
<td align=center>1</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>32000</td><td align=right>0</td><td>C5:7</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>0</td><td align=right>0</td></tr><tr><td>C5:8</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>0</td><td align=right>0</td><td>C5:9</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>0</td><td align=right>0</td></tr><tr><td>C5:10</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>32000</td><td align=right>717</td><td>C5:11</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>32000</td><td align=right>70</td></tr><tr><td>C5:12</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>32000</td><td align=right>187</td><td>C5:13</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>32000</td><td align=right>1506</td></tr><tr><td>C5:14</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>32000</td><td align=right>0</td><td>C5:15</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>32000</td><td align=right>0</td></tr><tr><td>C5:16</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>32000</td><td align=right>0</td><td>C5:17</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>32000</td><td align=right>1506</td></tr><tr><td>C5:18</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>0</td><td align=right>0</td><td>C5:19</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>0</td><td align=right>0</td></tr></table></center><hr width=25% align=center>
```

Comment: Why don't you use a DOM parser?

Comment: See [SimpleDOMParser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) or the native [DOM class](http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.dom.php).

Answer (score 0):

Now I haven't tried the code, but it's with the function preg_match_all() you gets all matches from a regex.

```
//gets the site
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://site.org');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch); 

//parse the data
preg_match_all('/[0-9]+(?=[^0-9]+(C5:2<|C5:6<|C5:13))/', $response, $matches);

//prints the parsed data
print_r($matches[0]);
```

http://php.net/preg_match_all

Comment: Great.  Now if I want to assign each one of the responses to an individual variable.  ie...
    $run_time_daily =     $matches['run_time_daily'];
    $pours_daily = $matches['pours_daily'];
    $product_run_count = $matches['product_run_count'];

Is this how it works?  I am not getting anything except a blank page now.